# Defining a grid using np.linspace and evaluating function over this grid

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I have the following grid of times defined:

```
T = 10000
tmin = 0
tmax = 10**20
t = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, T)
```

so my stepsize is somewhere around 10**16. I want to evaluate a function from tmin to tmax according to that stepsize. Is the following simply evaluating from tmin to 10,000 or over the full grid?

```
timedep_PD = np.zeros([t,Y])
for t in range(tmin,T):
    timedep_PD[t]= probdensity_func(x,t,0)
```

How can I evaluate this function from `tminx` to `tmax` in stepsizes of 
(tmax-tmin/T) while still storing in the form of `timedep_PD[t]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make it simple:

```
T = 10
tmin = 0
tmax = 10**2
t = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, T)

timedep_PD = np.zeros((len(t),T)) ##len(t) is T : np.zeros((T,T))
dt = ((tmax-tmin)/T)
k=0
for t in np.arange(tmin,tmax,dt):
    timedep_PD[k]= np.sin(t)
    print timedep_PD[k]
    k+=1
```

We also can use [np.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)